# Dev/Production Deployment of a Web App in Docker

Tags: docker, wordpress, deployment, web-applications

I'm running a web app (Wordpress, actually, but I think it mostly does not matter for the question). It is running in two Docker containers, one containing an Apache web server (via the official `wordpress` Docker image) and one containing a MariaDB. The containers are deployed using `docker compose` and the data is mounted from a folder on the host machine. My backup is done by running `mariabackup` in the MariaDB container and then backing up the web server files and database backup. I am using traefik as a reverse proxy.

From time to time, I want to perform major upgrades of the web app or do some development. For that, a develop copy of the site would be quite useful. The develop copy would not need to run the whole time. I think there would be two cases I would like to use it:

1. Copy the main instance ("production") to develop. Do some testing or development. Then drop the develop instance.
2. Make production read-only. Copy production to develop. Upgrade web app. Copy develop to production. Make production read-write.

What would be a good way to do this? I am leaning towards adding two more containers for my staging environment two my `docker-compose.yml` and then creating a bit of scripts (I was thinking about using Ansible, though I've never used that) which would do the copying. I am also considering using something like OverlayFS to avoid copying a lot of data. But I've also stumbled over tools like Vagrant and Trellis, and wonder whether one of them would be a better way to address my issue.